# Swift: Override can only be specified on class members

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, overriding, runtime-error

In my GameScene.swift file, there are errors that are causing the build to fail.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = location

        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
```

I am told that 'override can only be specified on class members'.

How should I fix this?

This is the whole thing:

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  Swipe Racer
//
//  Created by William Clark on 25/10/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Arc of Clark. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import Darwin

class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var swipes = SPSwipes()

    if swipes.no_of_swipes == 5 {
        var array = Array<UInt32>(count: 5, repeatedValue: 0)
        for i in 0 ..< 5 {
            array[i] = arc4random_uniform(100)}
        }

    if swipes.no_of_swipes == 10 {
        var array = Array<UInt32>(count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)
        for i in 0 ..< 10 {
            array[i] = arc4random_uniform(100)}
    }

    if swipes.no_of_swipes == 25 {
        var array = Array<UInt32>(count: 25, repeatedValue: 0)
        for i in 0 ..< 25 {
            array[i] = arc4random_uniform(100)}
    }

 func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = location

        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}

func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

There is also a syntax error at the bottom mentioned in the comment section.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're using `override` where it isn't applicable. Have you tried removing 'override' on the `update` method?

Comment: I did that on both functions but now at the bottom there is another error: consecutive declarations on a line must be seperated by ;. Thanks

Comment: That indicates there is a syntax error. Please share the whole class definition.

Comment: @DVPlusV Where do you mean?

Comment: You didMoveToView method is not closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add a "}" before the line

```
func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
```

Answer (score 1):

there is 2 answers one is that you used override somewhere you can't otherwise your missing a braket or a round braket